# Convert Numeric Date Time into AM PM Time in Redshift

Tags: sql, timestamp, amazon-redshift, type-conversion, numeric

I have a field called `tran_datetime` that is a 14 digit numeric field.

Values exist as 20130216131736 ... i.e. 2013-02-16 01:17:36 PM

In my query export I need to convert the *last 6 digits to a TimeStamp*.

Here is the closest version I found that works.

```
(SUBSTRING(tran_datetime,9,2) || ':' || SUBSTRING(tran_datetime,11,2) || ':' || SUBSTRING(tran_datetime,13,2)) ,
```

but this is returning it as 13:17:36. I am trying to find a way of converting it to the 01:17:36 PM format.

Something like this...

```
to_char((SUBSTRING(tran_datetime,9,2) || ':' || SUBSTRING(tran_datetime,11,2) || ':' || SUBSTRING(tran_datetime,13,2)), 'HH12:MI:SS')
```

or

```
cast((SUBSTRING(tran_datetime,9,2) || ':' || SUBSTRING(tran_datetime,11,2) || ':' || SUBSTRING(tran_datetime,13,2)) as TIMESTAMP)
```

But most everything I try gets an error, most commonly  `Timestamp out of range`

Comment: A `TIMESTAMP` includes both Date and Time. What did you want to set the `Date` component to? Can you explain your use-case -- there might be a better option for how you want to use it.

Comment: Hi John, I do not need the date at all. In my query I need only the retrieve the time from that field.

Comment: Can you provide more information about how you are going to *use* the time? For example, will you be calculating differences between times, or somehow displaying the time? That might influence the recommended method.

Comment: It will be put in a report, and then distributed to the users to verify times that tasks were started.

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you.

```
select to_char(cast('131736' as time),'HH12:MI:SS AM')
```

If I’ve made a bad assumption please comment and I’ll refocus my answer.

Comment: But where do I input my field name? I don't need to just convert that 1 time, I need to convert all times from the tran_datetime column.

Comment: @alexlunar - You can use substring(tran_datetime,9,13) or John's solution  should work too.

Answer (score 0):

This will convert it to a timestamp:

```
select to_timestamp(20130216131736::text, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')
```

Output:

```
2013-02-16 13:17:36+00
```

Taking that output, this will give you the format you desire:

```
select to_char(to_timestamp(20130216131736::text, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS'), 'HH12:MI:SS AM')
```

Output:

```
01:17:36 PM
```

To use it in a query, if the field is `when`:

```
select to_char(to_timestamp(when::text, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS'), 'HH12:MI:SS AM')
```

See also:

- Amazon Redshift documentation: [Datetime Format Strings](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_FORMAT_strings.html)
- PostgreSQL 8 documentation: [Data Type Formatting Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/functions-formatting.html)

Comment: Thank you John, Once I replaced the 20130216131736 with my actual field name, it does work that way.

Comment: Hi @alexlunar, if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: I did, but it says it wont show up since i have less than 15 reputation

Answer (score 0):

Based on John's example, here is the script that actually fixed this...

```
to_char(to_timestamp(act_veh.whse_lbr_tran_datetime::text, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS'), 'HH:MI:SS AM')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, It is working for me, s.start_time is column name and if you need year month and date you can pass as well:

to_char(dateadd(minute,330,s.start_time), 'HH12:MIPM')